# UID program resulting in Invalid Characters

Tags: linux, c

I'm not sure if this was the right group to post in because this topic could fit under multiple categories, but I hope you guys can help.

So I have a book and one of the programs in the book are as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "hacking.h"

   void usage(char *prog_name, char *filename) {
        printf("Usage:\t %s <data to add to %s>\n", prog_name, filename);
        exit(0);
    }

void fatal(char *);
void *ec_malloc(unsigned int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int file_descriptor;
    int userid;
    char *buffer, *datafile;

    buffer = (char *) ec_malloc(100);
    datafile = (char *) ec_malloc(20);
    strcpy(datafile, "/var/notes");

    if(argc < 2) {
    usage(argv[0], datafile);
    }

    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]); // Copy message into buffer

    printf("[DEBUG] buffer @ %p and holds %s\n", buffer, buffer);
    printf("[DEBUG] datafile @ %p and holds %s\n", datafile, datafile);

    // Open File
    file_descriptor = open(datafile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(file_descriptor == -1) {
        fatal("in main() opening file");
    }
    printf("file_descriptor: %i\n", file_descriptor);

    userid = getuid(); // Get real User ID

    // Write to File
    if(write(file_descriptor, &userid, 4) == -1) { // Write userid before file
        fatal("in main() writing userid to file");
    }
    write(file_descriptor,  "\n", 1); // Terminate line

    if(write(file_descriptor, buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1) {
        fatal("in main() writing to file");
    }
    write(file_descriptor, "\n", 1);

    // Closing File
    if(close(file_descriptor) == -1) {
    fatal("in main() closing file");
    }

    printf("Note has been saved\n");
    free(buffer);
    free(datafile);
}
```

So what that program is supposed to do is take the string entered on the command line and put it into a text file in var named notes. Before doing that, it is supposed to write the UID inside the file. When I run the program on root (I created it with root and ran it first with root), it works no problem and writes the UID to be \00\00\00\00 because it should be zero. However if I log out of my root account and go to my other account (which isnt root), I run it and I get the error that I dont have permission to open the file. That is because /var/notes was created using root. This all makes sense. So what i did was used

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/notes
```

to be able to access it on my user account. Then I re-ran the program above and it left the note I left to be copied into it, however the UID came out as unknown characters. Exactly, they are: \E8\00\00
Now that shouldn't be but how come this is happening? The UID on that account is 1000.

Comment: `0x03e8` is 1000 decimal.  are you sure it's not writing 03e80000 ?

Comment: @cas I am sure I copied and pasted

Comment: what does `hd /var/notes` show? (or `od` or `hexdump` or `xxd`)

Comment: @cas 00000000 00 00 00 00 0a 72 6f 6f 74 0a e803 00 00 0a 79 00000010 61 73 0a 00000013

Comment: and to the right of it it says |.....root......yas| (root was a note i wrote using root and yas was a note i wrote using my user account

Comment: immediately after the second line feed (0a) there is e803.  or 1000 decimal in little-endian format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that's happening is because you're mixing binary and text data in the output file.

`getuid()` returns a binary integer.  You should convert it to text like this:

```
char userid[32];   // change from int to character array
// . . .
snprintf(userid, sizeof(userid), "%d", getuid());
if (write(file_descriptor, userid, strlen(userid)) == -1) {
```

On another note, within the local context of this program, there's no need for dynamically allocated memory.  Consider these statements:

```
char *datafile = "/var/notes";
```

and

```
write(file_descriptor, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]))
```

The above two statements would eliminate the need for dynamic memory and eliminate at least one variable (`buffer`).

Dynamic memory allocation is highly associated with bugs and program errors.  Use it when necessary, but avoid it when not necessary.